# Add item to provider in flutter

Tags: flutter

What's the correct way to use provider with an api call?

My current setup, although I don't know if it's correct, is I have a response model and a Response class and the response model gets passed to the response class. the ui is using a provider. Heres's the code:

```
class InfoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
Future<Response> getSomeInfo(SomeInfo someInfo) async {
    try {
      final responseJson = await _provider.post('/info', someInfo.toJson());

      ResponseModel someResponse = ResponseModel.fromJson(responseJson['payload']);
      return Response.success(someResponse);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.toString() == 'refresh_token_not_found') return Response.unauthenticated();
      return Response.error(e.getError());
    }
  }

Future<Response> fetchInfo() async {
try {
  final responseJson = await _provider.get('info');
  if (responseJson['payload'].isEmpty) return Response.success([]);

  AllInfoResponse alLInfoResponse = AllInfoResponse.fromJson(responseJson['payload']);
  _allInfo = alLInfoResponse.AllInfoResponse;
  return Response.success(alLInfoResponse);
} catch (e) {
  if (e.toString() == 'refresh_token_not_found') return Response.unauthenticated();
  return Response.error(e.toString());
}
```

}
}

The ui has a future builder like this: `future: Provider.of<InfoProvider>(context).getSomeInfo(),`

So that all works, but how can I add some more items to the ui?

Here's my model:

```
class ResponseModel {
  final List<SingleResponseModel> ResponseModel;
  ResponseModel({this.ResponseModel});

  factory ResponseModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) => ResponseModel(
        ResponseModel: List<SingleResponseModel>.from(json.map((x) => SingleResponseModel.fromJson(x))),
      );
}

class SingleResponseModel {
  final String id;
  final String title;

  SingleResponseModel({
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });

  factory SingleResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SingleResponseModel(
      id: json['_id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;

    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this in your scenario is to wrap MaterialApp inside MyApp() in your main.dart file with MultiProvider. Try something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/provider#multiprovider You can place a ChangeNotifierProvider inside it.

Here is how you can access the values of ResponseModel in your UI:

```
final model=Provider.of<ResponseModel>(context,listen:false);
```

Don't forget to add getters and setters so that you can use notifyListeners() if you have any ui that depends on it.

This is how your model should look like:

```
class ResponseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<SingleResponseModel> _myModel;
  get myModel => _myModel;
  set myModel(List<SingleResponseModel> myModel) {
    _myModel = myModel;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is how you can display your data in a Text Widget (Ideally, you should use Selector instead of Consumer so that the widget only rebuilds if the value its listening to changes):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //other widgets
 Selector<ResponseModel, int>(
  selector: (_, model) => model.myModel,
  builder: (_, model, __) {
   return ListView.builder(
     itemCount: model.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return ListTile(
       title: Text(model[index].title),
       subtitle:Text(model[index].id),
       );
     },
   );
  }
 )
}
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Just added my model

Comment: @Jessica can you tell me what you're trying to do here? What do you mean by how can I add some more items to the ui?

Comment: I basically have a fetch all data function and an add new data function. My code above works well with the fetch all data function, but when there is a post request, and new data gets added to the backend, I want the ui to also recieve that new data

Comment: For that, you can do what I did above and use a Listview.builder() to display the data. I updated my answer above

Comment: Getting this error now: A build function returned null.

Comment: where is the error from? Try printing model[index].title on top of the return ListTile inside Listview's itembuilder.

Comment: Fixed that error. Now I;m just trying to display/fetch the data, but it isnt working

Comment: I tried calling `model.fetchInfo`, but it didn't work

Comment: where is model.fetchInfo I don't see it in your example above @Jessica

Comment: Also, how can I handle errors with Selector? Before, with `FutureBuilder`, I would get `snapshot.connectionState` and `snapshot.data.status`

Comment: I don't now what the output of your fetchInfo is but you have to set the values. Use final model=Provider.of<ResponseModel>(context,listen:false); then model.myModel= your new SingleResponseModel;

Comment: You can handle the errors where you are fetching the json data and not inside selector. It really isn't a good idea to do it in selector.

Comment: so I would do `final info = model.fetchInfo();` and I would handle the errors from the var of info? How can I do that if fetchInfo() is a future? I can't add await in front, since it's in `build(BuildContext context)` function

Comment: Should the selector be wrapped in a FutureBuilder widget?

Comment: wrap the ListView.builder with the FutureBuilder widget and not the selector

Comment: So then we go back to the original question, of how can I add an item to the provider

Comment: Simply append the item to the list then set it as model.myModel=newList;

Comment: @Jessica if this helped you, kindly accept and upvote my answer. Thank you.